# Load .ics file to add calendar event from application

Tags: ios, objective-c

To load .ics file from url I am using open url method as below

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
```

It's working fine.
But I want to load .ics file from application's bundle without URL. eg., I have file is **test.ics** file How can I load this file, can we load anyway it without URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the `ics` file locally

```
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@'icsName' withExtension:@'ics'];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:path];
```

---

```
- (IBAction)displayICS:(id)sender
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"ics"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    dc.delegate = self;
    [dc presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
-(UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to make as url with above way, bit nothing happens to load the file. I mean it's not loading file.